# Error In My Syntax MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm somewhat new to MySQL, so forgive me if this is something obvious. I'm attempting to create a new table but I continue to get the same error (1064). I have no idea what is wrong with my syntax, I am quite literally copying it from a book.

```
CREATE TABLE order
(order_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
fname VARCHAR(20),
lname VARCHAR(20),
CONSTRAINT pk_order primary key (order_id)
);
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Backticks(`) to resolve this:

```
CREATE TABLE `order`
(order_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
fname VARCHAR(20),
lname VARCHAR(20),
CONSTRAINT pk_order primary key (order_id)
);
```

Note: make sure that you always use back ticks for this table while querying.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91115

Answer (score 0):

order is a reserved keyword in mysql, so don't use it as a column or table identifier. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE orders(order_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,fname VARCHAR(20),lname VARCHAR(20),CONSTRAINT pk_order primary key (order_id));
```

This may be the correct query.